# Monospace Fonts vs. Monospace Fonts

Tags: windows, command-line, fonts

Why are some monospace fonts listed in the Command Prompt list, while some aren't?

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the [official requirements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247815) for a font to be listed in the console properties. There are several properties that the fonts needs to be meet, and then you can add “register it”—no pun intended—by adding it to the registry.

Here is a [graphical tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/) on adding fonts to the list. (It demonstrates at the end how some fonts won’t work.)

Comment: *If it is not a TrueType font, the face name must be "Terminal."* MFW

Comment: dead link for official requirements

Answer (score 2):

Some declare themselves as monospace in the font header, and some don't.

Comment: So I can just manipulate a couple of bits in the file and suddenly get a bunch of fonts in the command prompt? If so, which bits?

Comment: Depends on the type of font. And note that declaring a font monospace when it really isn't will hurt your brain.